# Android studio clipping corners in dialog

Tags: android

I made an `activity` that is using my custom `dialog` as its theme. I applied my `drawable` with rounded corners to the `activity's` outermost `PercentRelativeLayout` but the corners are `clipping`. Here is my custom `dialog` in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="myCustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Here is my `drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

Here is my `activity` in my `manifest`

```
 <activity android:name=".activities.NotSavedActivity"
              android:theme="@style/myCustomDialog">
    </activity>
```

When i start my activity, the corners are clipping as shown in the images below

[image] [image]

Here is my `activity's xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="15dp"
android:background="@drawable/not_saved_module">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Du har inte sparat, stäng ändå?"
    android:id="@+id/notSavedTextView"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/notSavedTextView">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/yes"
            android:text="Ja"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/no"
            android:text="Nej"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/yes"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/yes"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You see, you are not setting any background in your drawable. In fact your drawable is just a stroke with corners. Try to set some fill color ("solid" attr) in your drawable and you'll see, that all actually all is pretty OK. That background comes from `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` theme.

Set in your theme something like this

```
<style name="myCustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

or even

```
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/not_saved_module</item>
```

But in 2nd variant you don't need to set it in `activity` XML then